# Bootstrap: stack rows of divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to stack a various number of divs in multiple rows when theres not enough space to show them in a single row?

So what I mean is, imagine you have 20 divs but only 5 fit in the first row. Then there should be 4 rows with 5 items. 
On the other hand when we only have 3 items then there should only be one row with 3 items.

Comment: Flexbox makes this easy. Have a look here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Gerard pls provide this as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Okay, as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox makes this easy. Have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap has 12 columns per rows.  You can nest columns/rows but not recommend that you nest containers.

With that being said, you can have up to 12 columns per row.  To control how it is 'stacked' you classify which type of columns it belongs to.  See the demo.

https://codepen.io/pkshreeman/pen/LLYZqm

Resize the window, and you will see what it does for different settings.

Hope this helps.

This is the code used in demo:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> col-md-6 </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> col-md-6 </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> col-md-6 col-sm-6 </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> col-md-6 col-sm-6 </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2"> col-md-6 col-sm-2 </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2"> col-md-6 col-sm-2 </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">col-md-4 col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">col-md-4 col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">col-md-4 col-sm-6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">col-md-4 col-sm-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">col-md-4 col-sm-2
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">col-md-4 col-sm-2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this approach, but the problem was that this does not support a various amount of items

Comment: Oh okay, so it is dynamically changing?  Are you using the grow/shrink feature of the flexbox?  Does anyone know whether Bootstrap 4 incorporates this feature (I know they added flex feature, but not sure to what extent?).